# If any value from the first column is matching (partial/ full) in an another column in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, data.table, stringr

I have two lists, which are like following. I am looking for an output where every row of dat1 will match on complete column in dat, and on the basis of that, I will get the results

```
dat <- data.frame(v=c('apple', 'le123', 'app', 'being', 'aple',"beiling"))
dat1 <- data.frame(v1=c('app','123', 'be'))
```

I have tried following two alternatives but without success

```
test <- mapply(grepl, pattern=dat1$v1, x=dat$v)

str_detect(as.character(dat$v),dat1)
```

the output I am getting is

```
TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

but the desired output I am looking for is

```
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

How can I go ahead with this, every help is important

Answer (score 1):

We can `paste` the pattern dataset column ('dat1$v1') together by `collapse`ing with `"|"` and this will look for any matches.  It is basically telling that either one of these patterns are in the 'v' column of 'dat'

```
stringr::str_detect(as.character(dat$v),paste(as.character(dat1$v1), collapse="|"))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Note:  To avoid any substring mismatches it is better wrap with word boundary (`\\b`)

```
pat <-  paste0("\\b(", paste(as.character(dat1$v1), collapse="|"), ")\\b")
stringr::str_detect(as.character(dat$v), pat)
```

which seems to be not the case in the OP's data

#### Update

If the pattern list is very long, then we can loop over the patterns, get a `list` of logical `vector`s and `Reduce` it to single `vector`

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(as.character(dat1$v1), str_detect, string = as.character(dat$v)))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks akrun,  but it's just an example for a larger data set.  So my pattern column is long.. And can't really combine and paste it in 1 list

Comment: @ManuSharma  IN that, case, you can check the `Update` in my post

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, you can use `sqldf` and do this in SQL format:

```
require(sqldf)

dat <- data.frame(v=c('apple', 'le123', 'app', 'being', 'aple','beiling'))
dat1 <- data.frame(v1=c('app','123', 'be'))
sqldf("SELECT dat.* FROM dat JOIN dat1 on dat.v like ('%' || dat1.v1 || '%')")
```

And result would be:

```
        v
1   apple
2   le123
3     app
4   being
5 beiling
```